# Convert multidimensional array to Hash in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have input something like this:

```
input = [['abc',['xyz','1.1']], ['abc',['xyz','1.2']],['def',['lmn','3.14']]]
```

And I want to convert this to

```
{'abc'=>[{'xyz'=>'1.1'},{'xyz'=>'1.2'}],'def'=>[{'lmn'=>'3.14'}]}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more way to do it:

```
input.inject({}) { |a, (k, v)| a.merge(k => [Hash[*v]]) { |_, o, n| o + n } }
```

It was pointed out by Ilya that `merge!` should be preferred over `merge` since it has better performance characteristics.

Comment: `merge!` would be more efficient.

Comment: @kaikuchn
Excellent!

I have one more thing to do. How can I achieve this?


```{'abc'=>[{'xyz'=>{'value'=>1.1'}},{'xyz'=>{'value'=>1.2'}}],'def'=>[{'lmn'=>{'value'=>3.14'}}]}```

Comment: This is how you can do that:

    `input.inject({}) { |a, (k, (ik, v))| a.merge!(k => [{ik => { 'value' => v }}]) { |_, o, n| o + n } }`

But to be honest this is getting really complex really fast. So unless this is a one time thing you just want to execute in an irb, I'd suggest to do use expressive variable names and probably split that transformation up into parts such that it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `each_with_object`:

```
accumulator = Hash.new { |k,v| k[v] = [] }

input.each_with_object(accumulator) {|(f, s), memo| memo[f] << Hash[*s] }
#=> {"abc"=>[{"xyz"=>"1.1"}, {"xyz"=>"1.2"}], "def"=>[{"lmn"=>"3.14"}]}
```

Comment: Good answer. But why use `each_with_object` when you could just use `each`? This is what I have in mind: `input.each{ |f, s| accumulator[f] << Hash[*s] }`

Comment: @Raffael, you could of course use `each`, but that does not return `accumulator`. If, for example, you were to wrap this in a method, you would need the last line to be `accumulator`. `each_with_object`, by contrast, returns the object (`memo`). Moreover, `accumulator` could be substituted out, saving two statements when compared to using `each` and also confines the scope of `memo`.

Comment: Yes, after the call to `each` the result will be stored in the `accumulator`. Sorry, I thought this was obvious. If you want to return the result I do indeed suggest you add another line. I suggest this out of personal preference. I prefer clear and easily readable code over short code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
accumulated = {}

input.each { |k, v| accumulated[k]&.push(Hash[*v]) || accumulated[k] = [Hash[*v]] }

#=> accumulated
#=> {"abc"=>[{"xyz"=>"1.1"}, {"xyz"=>"1.2"}], "def"=>[{"lmn"=>"3.14"}]}
```

---

*If* you're using Rails, you can substitute the safe navigation operator (`&`) with `try()` if you find it to be more readable:

```
input.each { |k, v| accumulated[k].try(:push, Hash[*v]) || accumulated[k] = [Hash[*v]] }
```

Comment: Where does the `try` method come from? Neither [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html) or [NilClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html) have a try method defined in the docs.

Comment: @iain Oh derp – yeah, sorry, `try` is actually a Rails method. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please don't use "edited" or "updated" type tags when modifying your answer. Instead incorporate the information where you would have put it initially. We can see what changed and when if necessary. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/153968 explains it well.